# Evaluating google calendar "quick add" string instead of creating event

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

Google calendar supports ["quick add](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=36604)" strings, such as adding "meeting with Peter tomorrow 15:00 in room 2".

Do anyone know of a way to evaluate the string without before a calendar entry? Something along the lines of the following example:

```
REQUEST:
    action: "just_parse_don't_insert"
    text: "Lunch tomorrow 15:00 in room 2" 
RESPONSE:
    text: "Lunch"
    date: "05-03-2013"
    location: "room 2"
```

I can understand why Google would not offer this functionality, so alternatively, I'm looking for services/scripts (preferably JS) that offers similar functionality.